# Rezise page header windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

This is probably quite a simple question but very hard to google! I'm loading my header from external content so sometimes it will be longer than others. What I want is for the font to automatically resize so it fits on the page. Any ideas?

```
        <controls:PivotItem Name="Header" Header="some string that can be long" FontStretch="ExtraCondensed">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a converter that converts the string length to a font stretch/font size:

```
   <controls:PivotItem Name="Header" Header="{Binding theString}" 
         FontStretch="{Binding thestring, Converter={StaticResource stringToFontStretchConverter}}" 
         FontSize="{Binding thestring, Converter={StaticResource stringToFontSizeConverter}}">
```

although from a design perspective I wouldn't change the font depending on the string length

Comment: Indeed this is also a nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ViewBox control and put the Container Control within them.

Reference : http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/nrees/archive/2010/06/29/viewbox-wrappanel-and-a-scalable-ui-for-windows-phone-7.aspx